# How to get the Power Set Axiom from accepting "Subset Axiom"?

Tags: analysis, set-theory

This is the exercise 3.4.6(ii) on Tao's Analysis(4th edition) which is newly added after introduing the images and inverse images. The details are in the pictures.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leekX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd2ay.png)

I have solved the (i) but (ii) makes me confused. The first idea striking my mind is that taking functions as relations on $X\times Y$ and we can collect all the subset of it, if we take the Lemma as an axiom. Then by the axiom of specification we can get the subsets which are fit for function. Finally we can get the Power Set Axiom by the axiom of replacement. However, taking funcions as relations is introduced in the next section. Whether I can use them now or are there other better methods to solve this problem by just using former knowledge?

This is the definition of function before the exercise.
[image]

Comment: I think your proof sounds good, and I’m confused about your hang up. What would a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be other than a set of ordered pairs?

Comment: @Joe It's far from inevitable that a function is defined as a set of ordered pairs. Functions could be primitive, for instance.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen of course! Sorry I see now how my comment is poorly phrased and less-than-fully helpful. What I really mean is how does Tao define a function? In most of the set theory books I have looked at, functions are defined as certain sets of ordered pairs.

Comment: If functions are defined as Relations in the next chapter, how are they defined at this point? However they are defined will be relevent to the proof

Comment: I found an old edition of this book lying around. In this version, exercise 3.4.6 (ii) doesn't exist, and exercise 3.5.11 (also referenced in your edition!) is this problem, complete with a hint to 'construct the set of all subsets of $X\times Y$ that obey the vertical line test'